# How to destructure object props in Vue the way like you would do in React inside a setup?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, sanity

I am wondering how to destructure an object prop without having to type `data.title`, `data.keywords`, `data.image` etc. I've tried spreading the object directly, but inside the template it is undefined if I do that.

Would like to return directly `{{ title }}`, `{{ textarea }}` etc.

My code:

```js
   <template>
      <div>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { useSanityFetcher } from "vue-sanity";
    import { defineComponent, reactive, toRefs } from "vue";
    
    export default defineComponent({
      name: "App",
      setup: () => {
        const articleQuery = `*[_type == "article"][0] {
            title,
            textarea,
        }`;
    
        const options = {
          listen: true,
          clientOnly: true,
        };
    
        const res = useSanityFetcher<any | object>(articleQuery, options);
        const data = reactive(res.data);
    
        return toRefs(data);
      },
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Vue docs actually recommend not destructing props because of the way reactivity works but if you really want to something like this should work:

```js
const res = useSanityFetcher<any | object(articleQuery, options);
const data = reactive(res.data);

return toRefs(data);
```

Don't forget to import reactive and toRefs.

Comment: Is there really a downside to doing this? will it give errors?

Comment: I'm just going off the top of my head. Shouldn't error though. The only downside is a couple of extra lines of code

Comment: It's not working i've updated my code. Mind checking? - getting this: setup() return property "_dirty" should not start with "$" or "_" which are reserved prefixes for Vue internals. 
  at <App onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the sanity library. It may return a reactive object. In which case you may be able to do `const { data } = useSanityFetcher<any | object(articleQuery, options);

return toRefs(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `useSanityFetcher` is asynchronous, and `res` is reactive, it's incorrect to access `res.data` directly in setup because this disables the reactivity. Everything should happen in `computed`, `watch`, etc callback functions.

`title`, etc properties need to be explicitly listed in order to map reactive object to separate refs with respective names - can probably be combined with `articleQuery` definition or instantly available as `res.data`  keys

E.g.:

```
const dataRefs = Object.fromEntries(['title', ...].map(key => [key, ref(null)]))

const res = ...

watchEffect(() => {
  if (!res.data) return;
  for (const key in dataRefs)
    dataRefs[key] = res.data[key];
});

return { ...dataRefs };
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring the object is not the problem, see [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<script lang="ts">
//import { useSanityFetcher } from "vue-sanity";
import { defineComponent, reactive, toRefs } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  setup: () => {
    const res = {
      data: {
        title: 'Hi there'
      }
    }
    const data = reactive(res.data);

    return toRefs(data);
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

It may simply be the space between the filter and the projection in the GROQ expression

```js
const articleQuery = `*[_type == "article"][0]{ title, textarea }`;
```

See [A description of the GROQ syntax](https://www.sanity.io/docs/groq-syntax)

> A typical GROQ query has this form:
>
> `*[ <filter> ]{ <projection> }`